# How to read HttpRequest data in json sent from client on Apache server in PHP?

Tags: php, json, apache

Let say client is sending `json` data to the local server (in my case it is apache). I need to read the data (in `json` format ) which is sent by client to server and access the data on server side for coding further in PHP.

Kindly let me know by using `Apache` how to fetch the client data using PHP on the server side. 
I have tried the below code

```
 <?php
  $clientmessage= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];  // "e.g, this is client message"
  echo "this is a message sent to client which server recieved",  urldecode($clientmessage);
    ?>
```

but with that i am able to send the response from server to client (the same message back to client) but when i debug it using Xdebug or print it then the output of client message is wrong it is "XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=143445995265345" instead i should read "e.g, this is client message"

Why i am getting this output ? Kindly let me know by using Apache how to fetch the data (request) from the client on server side ?

Comment: It looks like you have never used PHP before. If that is the case, you should look for a basic PHP tutorial, as that matter is way too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Jason is a bit temperamental.

Comment: Try var_dump("$_POST"); Then find the variable you want from the client side